# use functions in a class - python

Tags: python, function, class

I have a couple of functions defined in my code and I want to be able to call them in one of my class.
I want to pass one of their name as an argument so I can select the right function to call in my class.

I looked for such things on internet but what I found is how to call a function defined in a class inside the same or another class. I can't define my functions inside my class because they also call other functions

So there's not too much but there's my code :

```
class _fonction_use_:
    def __init__(self,pos,function):
        self.pos=pos
        self.function=function
```

Where "function" would be the name of one of my functions defined outside the class.

So, if fonction_use belong to this class, I want something like fonction_use.function to return the function I would assigned it before.

Comment: 'I can't define my functions inside my class because they also call other functions' - that doesn't make sense. Functions inside a class, ie methods, can call anything they like.

Comment: Yes but this would be the same problem for me. How to call them then ?

Comment: To put it simple: you want to call a function having its name, right? First of all, why can't you pass the function itself, instead of the name?

Comment: Are you sure you want to reference by name? Since functions are first class objects you can pass the function itself. eg: if you had `def myfunc(): pass # do something` then you could call `obj = _fonction_use_(0, myfunc)`... You might want to read PEP8 regarding naming though...

Comment: My bad, yes I can pass the function itself (and I want to, it would be easier)

Comment: @user okay... I've made the comment into an answer...

Comment: I suggest you take a look at [dynamically adding instance- or classmethods](http://dietbuddha.blogspot.nl/2012/12/python-metaprogramming-dynamically.html), and follow the advice above of passing functions themselves instead of just their name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since functions are first class objects, you can pass them directly to your class.

```
def somefunc():
    pass # do something

class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, pos, function):
        self.pos = pos
        self.function = function

myclass = MyClass(0, somefunc)
```

Comment: Thanks, just because I begin in python I tried:
myclass =Myclass
then myclass.function = somefunc
and this doesn't work

Comment: @user I'm not quite following - are you saying this answer doesn't work or stating the code you'd already tried that didn't work?

Comment: Yes your answer is working, just because I'm not very familiar with class, I don't really understand why: myclass =Myclass then myclass.function = somefunc doesn't work

Comment: @User since classes are also first class objects, all you're doing by `myclass = Myclass` is making `myclass` an alias for the `Myclass` "definition" as it were... Your `myclass.function` is therefore then assigning a *class level attribute* to `Myclass`. When you use `Myclass(0, somefunc)` you're creating an *instance* of `Myclass` which has a `self` so that you can assign to the actual instance instead.

Comment: Thanks, I really didn't understand class...